# Change SSH pem file

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, openssh

I want to change my remote server SSH. Currently I login through a .**pem** file

```
ssh -l ubuntu -i .ssh/myfile.pem XX.XX.XXX.XXX
```

I tried to find how to change that access key but I found only that methor :

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048
cp id_rsa.pub authorised_keys 
scp authorized_keys ubuntu@XX.XX.XXX.XXX:/home/ubuntu/.ssh
```

I see no .pem file generated, plus how can I connect now ?
I want to make sure before I do anything so I don't lose ability to connect via SSH.
Should I remove the old key with :

```
ssh-keygen -R hostname
```

If yes, when ? after or before the scp ? if after this will remove both keys, if before then I wouldn't be able to perform scp !!!
I am a bot confused.
I see no .**pem** file in my remote, the pem file is only in my local .ssh folder. in remote .**ssh** I see :

[image]

Comment: @aicastell how do I delete the old SSH key in my remote?

Comment: Before deleting the old ssh key, be completely sure you can log into your remote server with the new public/private pair of keys. Once completely sure, do this:  ssh ubuntu@XX.XX.XXX.XXX rm /path/to/file.pem

Comment: I see no .pem file in my remote home/.ssh !!!

Comment: Not a programming question - try [su] ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With "ssh-keygen" command you generate a pair of public and private keys (by default stored in $HOME/.ssh).

Then you copy the public key in your remote server, and the private key in your local client (with permissions 0600). You can use "ssh-add" command to add the private key to the authentication agent to be able to connect to the remote server.

Comment: how do I delete the old SSH key in my remote?

Comment: If I just add a new public key to my remote then both new and old connection will work ? I want to delete the old , should I run ssh-keygen -R hostname ?

Comment: Use ssh verbose flag (-v) or strace to discover what's happening when connecting with ssh. In my remote server there is a /etc/ssl/certs directory with a lot of .pem files, but take care with that.

Comment: I found a lot !! is there a way toi know the right file ?